# EOS transaction lifecycle - Is there any way to view or catch incoming / pending / under validation transactions?

Tags: nodeos, cleos, transactions

I read a lot on the eosio developers page (https://developers.eos.io/welcome/latest/protocol-guides/transactions_protocol/#3-transaction-lifecycle).

I tried cleos and eosJS, but I couldn't figure out if it was somehow possible to somehow capture / view the incoming (to be processed), so  not yet confirmed, transactions.

Is it possible to somehow view / read these transactions, or is it necessary to install a mainnet nodeos? Can this be solved somehow with own nodeos?

(Hyperion, or peer2peer can help?)

Thanks in advance for the answers!